# How to rename a SageMaker notebook instance?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

On Amazon SageMaker, it's possible to edit most properties of a notebook instance when the instance is not active, but it does not seem possible to change its name.

Is there any way to rename an existing SageMaker notebook instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for using Amazon SageMaker.

SageMaker Notebook Instance's name cannot be edited.

Thanks,
Neelam

Comment: Why not? Notebook instances have storage attached so they can't just be deleted and recreated in order to change a name without a lot of inconvenience.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. This is annoying. It's unfortunately non-trivial for us to enable this in a self-service way for customers. We are actively pursuing alternatives for the future.  Thanks for the input. In the time being, it may be easiest to create a new Notebook Instance and transfer your data from one Notebook Instance to another using an external storage like S3 bucket.